# Replicar comportamiento de formulario normal con ajax al subir imagenes

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

Buenas estoy dandole vueltas a esto desde hace mas de 3 horas por eso solicito su ayuda.
Necesito replicar el comportamiento de un formulario normal que carga una imagen y la envia a php para luego subirla a mi base de datos. Intente lo siguiente.

```js
const file=document.getElementById("file");
const btn=document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener("click",presclick);
function presclick()
{
    const archivos=file.files;

        var formData=new FormData();
        formData.append("img",archivos);
        var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open("POST","agregarimg.php");
        xhr.send(formData);
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if(xhr.status==200&&xhr.readyState==4)
            {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }
}
```

```html
<input id="file" type="file">
<button type="button" id="btn">Enviar</button>
```

```html
<?php
header("Acces-Control-Allow-Origin:*");

$archivos;
if(isset($_FILES["img"]))
{

 $archivos=$_FILES["img"];

 $imgtemporal=$_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
 $data=file_get_contents($imgtemporal);
 $conexion=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba","usuario","contraseña");
 $conexion->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
 $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $consulta="INSERT INTO imgprueba (img) values (:img)";
 $respuesta=$conexion->prepare($consulta);
 $respuesta->bindValue(":img",$data);
 $respuesta->execute();
 $mensaje="Se subio la imagen"
 echo "se subio la imagen"
 
}

?>
```

Sin embargo al parecer en el archivo php no recibo la imagen para poder subirla a la base de datos. Intente cambiando el "$_FILES" por "$_POST", y si me recibe el archivo, pero me sale el siguiente error

> [10-Jul-2020 22:10:54 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset
> 'tmp_name' in /home/hiddenso/public_html/....

Que estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hace un tiempo tuve un problema parecido, ya que me hice la misma pregunta que tu, hice muchas pruebas en ese tiempo, y me di cuenta de que si querias subir archivos mediante `ajax`, no podias subirlos mediante un `FileList` ya que:

> Me di cuenta que al subir el `FileList`, php no interpretaba bien este
> `FileList`, haciendo que la llave que enviaras contuviera un elemento
> en el cual sus datos son inaccesibles por PHP, en el caso de que el
> metodo fuese POST se guardaba en `$_POST`, y en el caso de que la peticion fuese
> `GET` se guardaba en `$_GET` mediante la clave.

Intente de varias maneras obtener los datos del `FileList` desde PHP, pero sus datos nunca me fueron accesibles, asi que intente otra cosa:

Enviar un array de elementos `File` tal que asi:

```
[File, File, File, File]
```

Pero al hacerlo de esa forma php nisiquiera reconoció la llave que le di a esos valores, lo interpreto al parecer como texto.

Asi que intente una ultima opcion, en su lugar de usar un `FileList` o un array de `Files`, lo que hice fue ir añadiendo los archivos con ciertos nombres mediante un ciclo de esta manera:

```js
function presclick()
{
    const archivos=file.files;
    const sizeArchivos=Array.from(archivos).length;
    var formData=new FormData();

    for(let i = 0; i < sizeArchivos; i++){
      formData.append(`img_${i+1}`, archivos[i]);
    }

    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest;
    xhr.open("POST","agregarimg.php");
    xhr.send(formData);
    xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if(xhr.status==200&&xhr.readyState==4)
        {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
}
```

cuando hice aquello los archivos ya no quedaban grabados en `$_POST` o `$_GET` siempre llegaban al apartado `$_FILES`, y son accesibles con el nombre que le pusiste a cada uno:

```
<?php

   $imagen1 = $_FILES['img_1'];

?>
```

Aunque lo ideal no es ir guardando las imagenes de esa manera, en su lugar optaria por un ciclo `foreach` para subirlas, si es que quieres subirlas todas de golpe:

```
<?php

  foreach($_FILES as $file => $fileInfo){
      //Desde aqui irias subiendo tus files.
  }

?>
```

Asi fue como me funciono a mi anteriormente.

Comment: Increible, me funciono, aun estoy analizando el codigo para entender tu logica pero funciono.